# Pyside6 QMessageBox unable to make the QMesageBox appear in the middle

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside6

Hi i am unable to make my QmessageBox appear in the middle it keep appearing in the top left corner for some reason

This is my code

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox
from PySide6.QtGui import QScreen

class AlertDialog:
    def __init__(self, title, message, icon=QMessageBox.Information):
        self.title = title
        self.message = message
        self.icon = icon
        self.result = None

    def show(self):
        message_box = QMessageBox()
        message_box.setIcon(self.icon)
        message_box.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        message_box.setText(self.message)
        message_box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)

        screen = QScreen()
        screen_geometry = screen.geometry()

        message_box.setGeometry(
            (screen_geometry.width() - message_box.width()) / 2,
            screen_geometry.bottom() - message_box.height() - 20,  
            message_box.width(),
            message_box.height()
        )

        self.result = message_box.exec_()
```

However it keep appearing in the toprigth corner for some reason

Comment: Use `QApplication.primaryScreen()`, not `QScreen()`. The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qscreen.html) clearly shows that there's no such constructor, meaning that you shouldn't be able to create such an instance. In fact, PyQt *correctly* raises a `TypeError` exception when trying to do that. I don't know why PySide allows doing `QScreen()`, but that's a PySide bug.

Comment: Also note that, by default, Qt always tries to show dialogs in the center of the current screen (or the center of the window used for the parent argument): you should not try to change its `geometry` property unless you really know what you're doing, and especially using arbitrary adjustments. If your issue is that the message box is not properly centered by default, then you're probably asking the wrong question (see [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)), and we need further details about your environment: OS/Qt versions, and window manager info if you're on Linux.